Discarding VM state when starting it via VBoxManage startvm
Using VirtualBox, what is the equivalent of shutting down the running VM while discarding the new state?
With the GUI I can close the vm display or stop it via the GUI manager, and the dialog shows me a checkbox to "restore «name of last snapshot»" along with the "power off" option.
What is the equivalent for VBoxManage controlvm xxx poweroff? on the help/manual I don't see any parameters for it.
Alternatively, Or even better, is there way to start the VM such that simply killing the process (for example, host shutdown) the new state will be automatically discarded?
